# Timeshift setup: how to backup system with programs and all theirs configs, but without Video, Music etc?

Tags: backup, rsync, timeshift

I only make rare snapshots on an external drive (RSYNC option). I would like to backup all my programs with all their configuration settings as I have them now, but when I restore my system all programs are reset to their defaults as if newly installed.

I see an option to include all home files, but I don't want Timeshift to backup my Vido, Music etc (I do that by other methods if I need to).

I imagine the configurations I want to save are set under `/home` option of Timeshift.

**Is the "Include hidden" option (for `/home`) supposed to provide what I ask** - while "Include all" would save also Videos, Music etc?

Or is the result influenced by options for `/root`? *Are* [those options](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230183/925128) affecting what I ask?

[image]

Also: considering my stated goal, is there a difference between the results of restoring a snapshot on top of my *existing system* compared to restoring it on a *new empty partition*?

Comment: Did you try restoring the backup created with these settings? Let's say I go with "Include hidden" with my home directory. Does it erase other files (such as videos, documents, other non-hidden files) in my home when I perform a restore later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open `timeshift` Then click settings and go to the filters tab, you can exclude the music and video folders. The include hidden option backs up your hidden direct (the folders that begin with .) and unless you keep your videos and music in hidden files, you should be fine. If you turn on the include root option, it backs up the `/root` directory, so if you wanted to back those up, then sure, knock yourself out.

Restoring to existing system just overwrites your current system with the backup. Restoring to an empty partition does exactly what it says.

Comment: So "Include hidden" for `/home` is the answer?

Comment: Your question says you want to backup your system without videos and music, so include hidden and exclude your video and music folder (that is in your home folder) to backup the system completely.

Comment: Include hidden means that hidden files and folders are backed up (right click on an empty spot in your home directory and turn on show hidden). Hidden files and folders are usually config files that the system needs so I would keep those on. 

If you click on the Filters tab and click add folders, you can select the Music and Video folders. Then they would appear in the Filters tab. You can then turn off the backing up of videos and music by clicking the - button next to Videos/Music entry

Comment: Include all includes normal files and directory’s along with hidden files and folders. Exclude all files backs up all system files without the specified home directory. Include only hidden files would save configuration files but not normal Files and directory’s in your home directory. You would use include only hidden files if you want to reset your home directory without messing with your application configs. So if you want to backup your entire home directory and keep configs but exclude normal files, (which include music and videos) choose Include only hidden files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107265/discussion-between-thebuntunewb-and-cipricus).

Comment: `Include only hidden files would save configuration files but not normal Files and directory’s in your home directory` - that is exactly what I want. That's what I meant: "Include hidden" should be enough for my purpose, *no need to specifically exclude Music etc in "Settings"*, except maybe in order to be sure.

Comment: @TheBuntuNewb Let's say I go with "Include hidden" with my home directory. Does it erase other files (such as videos, documents, other non-hidden files) in my home when I perform a restore later?

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara, no, you are simply including hidden files along with your backup