# Timeshift setup: what is the result of the different `/root` options?

Tags: backup, rsync, timeshift

This is related to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230179/925128) I have posted, but this is different: I just wonder what are the different options for `/root` doing.

My intention is to save my system with all programs and theirs configuration settings and be able to restore it in the state it is now even on an empty partition. I see that the default is "Exclude all".

[image]

That is a bit puzzling to me. ***What exactly is excluded in this way, and what are the other two options including?***

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says: *User home directories are excluded by default unless you enable them here*.

It is not designed to backup user files, only system files. So no user's files should be backup by default.

But if you really want to include some user's files and folders, you could do it as shown on the picture. Including hidden files will backup user's configuration folders and files. Including all will backup all folders and files.

> Timeshift is similar to applications like rsnapshot, BackInTime and
>   TimeVault but with different goals. It is designed to protect only
>   system files and settings. User files such as documents, pictures and
>   music are excluded. **This ensures that your files remains unchanged
>   when you restore your system to an earlier date.** If you need a tool to
>   backup your documents and files please take a look at the excellent
>   BackInTime application which is more configurable and provides options
>   for saving user files.

[Reference](https://teejeetech.in/timeshift/)

So don't use it for backup and restore user's files. Only hidden user's files and directories backup -> restore could be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for this clear comment. It's clear for me that only hidden user's file can be integrated for backup concerning the /home directory. But concerning the /root directory, it's not clear for me, what is the advantage/disadvantage of including/excluding this. What kind of files or in there? Should it e.g. be interesting to include there also the hidden files?
Thanks for the information!

Comment: @KristofAllaert you can ask a new question about that topic - might be of interest to others